# What is the recommended way of managing admin-level passcodes?

Tags: passwords, admin, software-design

**For context,** I am currently developing a bit of software for a machine, when this machine is left by the operator (i.e. running without supervision), its door must be locked. This is all fine.

When the operator gets back and wants to unlock the software again, they must enter a simple 4-digit passcode. Then the door unlocks again.

Additionally, a supervisor or manager (or operator with the code I suppose) can enter another 4-digit passcode to enter a settings page. They could also change the operator passcode, etc.

Lastly, there's an Admin level. They can change actual parameters that shouldn't be touched by any other than the owner of the machine/someone with thorough knowledge of the system (like a service-person). This admin level can also be entered with a(nother) 4-digit code.

**Problem:** The problem arises when a supervisor changes passcodes. If they enter a password that happens to be identical to that of the admin, the software throws an exception.

**How do I actually handle this exception?**

I obviously cannot say "password in use, please use a different one"... That would give the admin password away. Should I let them choose their new passcode, and change the admin passcode one value higher? Admins would know of this behaviour, so if the default admin passcode doesn't work, they simply try passcode++.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I'd prefer to handle the exception properly, not change the way the login works. As this has already been deployed. (though I can see whether I could do so in future versions)

Comment: You are mixing function ("what does the user want to do") with the access check. If possible I would separate the two and identify the intended action first (perhaps with a single digit) and then enter the 4-digit code for access. That makes function plus code five digits, not sure if that works?

Comment: I suppose it would then work a bit like a username+password. The supervisor simply wouldn't be able to edit the first digit if I'm understanding you correctly. 

I suppose I should specify I'd rather handle the exception properly than change the method of entering passcodes though, I will edit the post